# HTPP_REQUEST_HEADERS missing when sending a soap request through soap client

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have recently upgraded from jdk8 to jdk17 and for this I have updated few of my dependencies in POM and added a few new ones , below are the dependencies

```
 <jaxws-maven-plugin.version>2.6</jaxws-maven-plugin.version>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>`
```

After making these updates , when I am sending a soap request using my soap client, HTTP Request Headers are missing when I try to fetch them in my Soap Message Handler.

```
final Map headers = (Map) context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
```

context is of type SOAPMessageContext

in above code headers turn out to be null

I was expecting that HTTP REQUEST HEADERS will be present because they were present before the upgrade.

Comment: Did you look at the release notes for the dependency used in that code? Perhaps it changed how the headers should be retrieved.

Comment: @Jorn I i did , there is no specific mention of a different way and moreover other headers are present in the soap context , only the request headers are missing